# I want show only data for today

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data  according to current date. data only show on current date

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,submit_date,suppliers,comments,van_temperature from diary_user_form_storage  where category_name='delivery_form'");
```

Comment: `diary_user_form_storage` is not a wordpress table. which plugin creates it ?

Comment: You just need to add a where clause, i.e. where 'submit_date' == todays date?

Comment: ProEvilz@i hvae solved this thanks for your suggestion man

Answer (score 0):

Well dear thanks for your effort.I solved this .here is answer.

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,submit_date,unit_data,temperature_in,temperature_out,time_in,category from diary_user_form_storage  where category_name='opening' and DATE(`submit_date`) = CURDATE()");
```